# What does "Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error" mean?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, error-handling

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error.  
If you notice further problem, try restarting the computer.  
Send an error report to help fix this problem
```

Since I upgraded from 10.01 to 12.04 I get this every time.

details are

> executive path-------user/lib/indicator-application/indicator-application-service...
>   Package--------------indicator-application0.50-0ubuntu1
>   Problem type---------crash

Answer (score 1):

`apport` is a debugging tool that is used to generate crash reports. This was not enabled by default in previous versions but in Ubuntu 12.04 it is. To avoid this, the Apport can be disabled by force. *One drawback of doing it will be that you wont see the crash report.*

To disable apport, you need to modify the `/etc/default/apport` file. Use the command below to open the file in GEdit text editor:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/apport
```

The content of the file is:

```
# set this to 0 to disable apport, or to 1 to enable it
# you can temporarily override this with
# sudo service apport start force_start=1
enabled=1
```

Change the `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`. Save and close the file and the pop-up should stay away.

Comment: thanks very much, I switched to Xubutu, which is much better